# Angular $resource.save() not working?

Tags: angularjs, http, post, controller, resources

I am trying to create a web app with Angular, and I need some help.  I need to `POST` data to an api.  Rather than using `$http` (which works), I'd like to use `$resource`, and `save()`.

I've also used `GET` and `query` so far, and they work fine.  But when I try to call `save()`, I never get a response.  I also don't see a `POST` request go through when I check on the server side.

Here's my code for the `$resource` factory (normally with my actual API url, of course)

```
.factory('ExamplePosts', function($resource) {
    return {
        all: $resource('http://my.website.com/api/')
    };
});
```

In my controller, I can run `ExamplePosts.all.query()` or `.get()`, and retrieve the results.  (I also see the request in my server logs.)

I then tried running `ExamplePosts.all.save()`, and I did not see a `POST` request on the server logs.  I can post to it through forms and it works, but there seems to be a problem with Angular.

Appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

Comment: What did you pass to the `save` function? the syntax is `ExamplePosts.all.save(paramsObj, dataObj, successFn, errorFn)`

Comment: @WayneEllery I just did some dummy data.  `.save({"id":123})`

Comment: It's supposed to be `.save(null, {id: 123});`

Comment: @WayneEllery no luck with that either...

Comment: @WayneEllery interesting...the Chrome Network logs show that Angular is sending an OPTIONS request, not POST.  Any way to change that?

Comment: What's the url you are using? Is it a different domain to your angular app?

Comment: Yes, it is.  I've set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` to `*` temporarily, but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70495/discussion-between-wayne-ellery-and-caleb).

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to add a prefix "$" to the save method as .$save() not .save() read this for more on those that need the $prefix [read more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: No you don't. You can use either $ for the returned objects or the without it for the instance of the resource class

Comment: Neither method worked.  Still seeing nothing on the server side. (only GET requests work)

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the developer tool to verify that the post is working and verify the request payload. Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWU4f6AgWKkjEqozPEvm?p=preview) of it working. If the post is working correctly then it's an issue on the server side and not the client

Comment: @WayneEllery didn't see this message before....the POST did go through on the Plunkr page.

Comment: Is there still an option request happening. If so can you check the response headers?